# Cannot sync with the NTP server

Tags: ntp

I am using lubuntu Linux 18.04 Bionic. When I print `ntpq -pn` I cannot see that my computer is synced with my desired NTP server.

I have tried several tutorials like here: [LINK](https://blog.selectel.com/synchronizing-servers-ntp/). I took the NTP servers from Google [HERE](https://developers.google.com/time/guides) and included the all 4 servers to my config file.

Then, I did the following things in order to sync with one of the Google NTP servers:

1. `sudo service stop`
2. `sudo service ntpdate time1.google.com` and received a log `ntpdate[2671]: adjust time server 216.239.35.0 offset -0.000330 sec`
3. `sudo service start`

Here is my `/etc/ntp.conf` file:

```
driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift
leapfile /usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list

statistics loopstats peerstats clockstats
filegen loopstats file loopstats type day enable
filegen peerstats file peerstats type day enable
filegen clockstats file clockstats type day enable

restrict -4 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited
restrict -6 default kod notrap nomodify nopeer noquery limited

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict ::1
restrict source notrap nomodify noquery

server time1.google.com iburst
server time2.google.com iburst
server time3.google.com iburst
server time4.google.com iburst
```

After doing the steps above, I got this result from `ntpq -pn`:

`remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
+216.239.35.0    .GOOG.           1 u   33   64    1   36.992    0.519   0.550
+216.239.35.4    .GOOG.           1 u   32   64    1   20.692    0.688   0.612
*216.239.35.8    .GOOG.           1 u   36   64    1   22.233    0.088   1.091
-216.239.35.12   .GOOG.           1 u   32   64    1   33.480   -0.218   1.378`

Why my computer is not synced?

EDIT:

Here is my log output after `sudo systemctl status ntp.service`:

```
ntp.service - Network Time Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ntp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-01-17 11:37:33 CET; 17min ago
     Docs: man:ntpd(8)
  Process: 2704 ExecStart=/usr/lib/ntp/ntp-systemd-wrapper (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 2712 (ntpd)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ntp.service
           └─2712 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 105:108

Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: proto: precision = 1.750 usec (-19)
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list'): good hash
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: leapsecond file ('/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list'): loaded, e
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen and drop on 0 v6wildcard [::]:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen and drop on 1 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen normally on 2 lo 127.0.0.1:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen normally on 3 wlan0 192.168.86.26:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen normally on 4 lo [::1]:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listen normally on 5 wlan0 [fe80::71d6:ec6e:fa92:b53%4]:123
Jan 17 11:37:33 ELAR-Systems ntpd[2712]: Listening on routing socket on fd #22 for interface updates
```

Comment: Anything in the logfiles?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Updated the question

Comment: Are you sure your time is not synced? If you are using the raspberry pi - you cannot sync it properly over time because it has no memory and power to keep the time stable.

Comment: @DanFromGermany How can I be sure that I am synced then? I am using ASUS Tinker Board, it has 2Gigs of RAM and armf architecture

Comment: How do you? Check a clock that you know it is synced and compare it to the time on the computer. Or change the time to something very wrong then restart the computer and see if it turns back to a realistic time. I am pretty sure your time is getting synced but the computer won't keep it stable. There are no errors or anything in your outputs.

Comment: Everything you have shown here indicates that your machine is synced, the output if `ntpq -pn` has one line with a star in front of it, indicating it's currently synced to 216.239.35.8. How are you concluding that it is not synced ?

Comment: @nos I am looking at offset values and I thought it should be very tiny. Also I requested to sync with the time1 and got a response that it is synced that npqt -p shows a different synced server

Comment: It is very tiny. Only 0.088 miliseconds. Even a hundret times worse, 8.8 miliseconds, would be within what one could expect from NTP. And ntpdate only runs a one time only sync, it does not tell ntpd to keep sync to that server.

Answer (score 0):

Your system time actually is getting synced but is running off very quick.

The Raspberry Pi, Arduino, Asus Tinker and the other PCB single-board computers have no onboard RTC (real time clock) and no battery to keep it up constantly. It has nothing to do with RAM or current, but simply the fact that there is no hardware clock on the computer.

On my raspberry pi, the time went off several minutes within an hour.
The "software clock" on the computer is impacted by system load and is very unstable.

An RTC extension (for RPI) looks like this:

[image]
(Source: www.robotshop.com)

Comment: Well I didn't downvote, but the OP has not mentioned using a raspberry pi, nor is there any info that keeping the time across reboot is the actual issue.  (In fact the OP has not demonstrated there is any issue at all so far). Also if you are using a rasbperrypi and using NTP - the clock isn't going to drift when running.

Comment: Didn't downvote either. But after looking through some articles, it seems that embedded machines can actually sync using NTP

Comment: @nos the OP has mentioned (in the comments) he is using an ASUS Tinker (which is similiar to RPI and has no RTC either). The machines can sync and I am kinda sure your clock actually is syncing but it's drifting. The software clock is not stable. It would be interesting how much the clock is wrong on your side.

Comment: @Edmung I am wrong with 1 thing tho: I assumed the suggested interval to sync is about once or twice a day, to not flood ntp servers. Actually the suggested time is the default time of 1024 seconds... at nos I must admit my information is outdated. If you sync the time every 5 minutes there should be no drifting. (as you said, an off of < 10 ms is still super accurate)

Comment: ntpd runs continuously and it is clever enough to figure out when it needs to contact the server, depending on latency and how accurate the local clock is. ntpd learns how much your local clock drifts over time compared to the ntp server, and it continuously ensures the local clock is in sync with the clock of the NTP server, it is not a "set the time once every x minute" situation, as would be if you just run e.g. the "ntpdate" tool. You do not need to worry about overloading the NTP servers.